# Why has my close vote seemingly disappeared from this question?

Tags: discussion

I voted to close this question this morning. The system even automatically left a comment with the reason I gave! [Need help with accessing my school admin's username & password to un-install the securly certificate on MacBook Air](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/404333/need-help-with-accessing-my-school-admins-username-password-to-un-install-the)

Around halfway through the day, I noticed the "close" link had a "(2)" next to it, so at least one other person had also voted to close.

As of this evening, there are no numbers by the close link. It looks like my own close vote might have disappeared as well.

What could have caused the close votes to disappear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After your close vote, others arrived to close the question. That cleared all the votes immediately.

Subsequent to that closure, reopen vote criteria were passed to reopen it.

Comment: Sorry that was my fault. I still had the tab open from before the question was edited, and I agreed to close the question based on the previous revision, but after I closed the question I noticed I'd been shown an older revision and agreed it should be left open given the newest edit, so I reopened it.